# PreparedStatement select with php not working as expected

Tags: php, sql, select, prepared-statement

I have this query:

```
SELECT id, result, ip_address, added_date
FROM results
WHERE course_id = ( 
SELECT id
FROM courses
WHERE course =  'informatica'
AND macro_course_id = ( 
SELECT id
FROM macro_courses
WHERE macro_course =  'scienze-matematiche-fisiche-e-naturali'
AND organization_id = ( 
SELECT id
FROM organizations
WHERE organization =  'universita-degli-studi-di-torino'
AND city_id = ( 
SELECT id
FROM cities
WHERE city =  'torino'
AND region_id = ( 
SELECT id
FROM regions
WHERE region =  'piemonte' ))))) ORDER BY id DESC
```

And i'm using this code to do it with a preparedstatement

```
public function getResults($region, $city, $organization, $macro_course, $course) { //works
    //added_date=datetime : YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
    echo "SELECT id, result, ip_address, added_date
    FROM results
    WHERE course_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM courses
    WHERE course =  '$course'
    AND macro_course_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM macro_courses
    WHERE macro_course =  '$macro_course'
    AND organization_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM organizations
    WHERE organization =  '$organization'
    AND city_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM cities
    WHERE city =  '$city'
    AND region_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM regions
    WHERE region =  '$region' ))))) ORDER BY id DESC"; //just for me to know what query is being executed 


    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare(("
    SELECT id, result, ip_address, added_date
    FROM results
    WHERE course_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM courses
    WHERE course =  ?
    AND macro_course_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM macro_courses
    WHERE macro_course =  ?
    AND organization_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM organizations
    WHERE organization =  ?
    AND city_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM cities
    WHERE city =  ?
    AND region_id = ( 
    SELECT id
    FROM regions
    WHERE region =  ? ))))) ORDER BY id DESC

  "))) {
        $return = array();
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $course, $macro_course, $organization, $city, $region);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $i = 0;
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                print_r($row);//this is never reached
                continue;
                $s = new Result($row['result'], $row['added_date'], $row['id']);
                $return[$i] = $s;
                $i+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

The problem is that this function returns 0 rows and 0 errors (checked with `$this->mysqli->error`), it seems that $row = $stmt->fetch() is always false.

However, if i copy and execute on PHPMyAdmin the output i get at the function top, i see

```
Showing lines 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query time 0.0003 sec)
```

So the query returns a line but it is not catched by php. What am i missing? How can i fix this?

Comment: you can fix it by learning **proper mysqli syntax** from manual, or - better - by using PDO.

Comment: Did you check your `query` works without server side.?

Comment: the query itself looks dazzling to me. can't you make it just one straight query with joins?

Comment: He's already using pdo...I would say to restructure his tables and use join if necessary, 6 queries in 1 go is nasty...

Comment: @Ranjith Read **all** the question: `However, if i copy and execute on PHPMyAdmin the output i get at the function top, i see "Showing lines 0 - 0 ( 1 total, Query time 0.0003 sec)"` of course it works, otherwise PMA would display that there is some error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you used `$stmt-fetch()` two times here

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

Remove the `if ($stmt->fetch())` condition, it will work as expected.

**EDIT**

from docs

**Note that all columns must be bound by the application before calling $stmt->fetch().**

You have to bind the result before calling `$stmt->fetch()` like this

```
/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($name, $code);
```

Comment: Sometimes its a good idea to close a too localized question or two, instead of answering it. Just for sake of it.